# What property does an identity relation has?

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, relations, descriptive-set-theory

Reflective is obvious, but what about the other properties?

It's weird when we check the symmetric property of the identity relation. The symmetric property happens when (in a matrix representation) the upper triangle and the lower triangle that exists in a matrix that's divided by the matrix's diagonal get mirrored. Also, you can make a graph representation of the relation and see that it's just loops. So is it symmetric or not? (also, check out if it's antisymmetric or not because I think the matrix representation shows that it's antisymmetric)

Comment: It is symmetric. If you swap upper and lower triangles, you get the same identity matrix.

Comment: Reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity.

Comment: It is antisymmetric. Just plug into the definition: $xRy$ and $yRx$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=y$, to get $x=y$ and $y=x$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=y$.

Comment: In short, it's an equivalence relation. But it also has the substitutivity property, which other equivalence relations don't. For any property $P$, we have $P(x)$ & $x=y$ $\Rightarrow$ $P(y)$. (This is one-place substitutivity.)